# How can I make one table that "overrides" another?

Tags: sql, mysql, view

Suppose I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE A(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    x INT,
    y INT
)

CREATE TABLE B(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    x INT,
    y INT,
)
```

Table A contains data brought in from another vendor while table B is our data.  For simplicity, I've made these tables be exactly the same in terms of schema, but table B would likely be a superset of table A (it would contain some columns that table A wouldn't in other words).

What I would like to do is create a view C with columns id, x, and y such that the values come from table B unless they're NULL in which case they would come from table A.  For instance, suppose I had the following:

```
INSERT INTO A (id, x, y)
VALUES (1, 2, 3);

INSERT INTO B (id, x, y)
VALUES (1, NULL, NULL);

INSERT INTO A (id, x, y)
VALUES (2, 3, 4);

INSERT INTO B (id, x, y)
VALUES (2, 5, 6);

INSERT INTO A(id, x, y)
VALUES (3, 4, 5);

INSERT INTO B(id, x, y)
VALUES (3, 5, NULL);
```

So that if I select * from C, I'd get the following rows:

```
(1, 2, 3)
(2, 5, 6)
(3, 5, 5)
```

How could I create such a view?

Answer (score 8):

You could join the tables together with a `left join`, and then select the right columns with a `case`:

```
select  case when A.x is null then B.x else A.x end
,       case when A.y is null then B.y else A.y end
from    A
left join
        B
on      A.id = b.id
```

Comment: Or use COALESCE (if you are allowed to do that in a view, I don't know).

Comment: From the question, values should be from **B** by default, not A.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
Create view C as
select  B.ID,
        coalesce(B.x,A.x) x,
        coalesce(B.y,A.y) y
from    B
left join A
on   B.ID = A.ID
```